# R - Transform Data frame to Time Series

Tags: r, time-series

I have a Google stock data. It has two columns Date(Daily Data) and Close i.e. Google closing index.

```
Date    Close
10/11/2013  871.99
10/10/2013   868.24
10/9/2013    855.86
10/8/2013   853.67
10/7/2013   865.74
10/4/2013   872.35
10/3/2013   876.09
10/2/2013   887.99
10/1/2013   887
9/30/2013   875.91
9/27/2013   876.39
9/26/2013   878.17
9/25/2013   877.23
9/24/2013   886.84
```

and its in csv format and I read it through read.csv which return data frame object. When I tried to transform it into timeseries / ts() object, it returns unwanted numbers.

Please help me to convert data frame into ts() object.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

I suggest using `xts` instead of `ts` as it has lot of functions especially for financial time series.
If your data is in data.frame `DF` then you can convert it to `xts` as follows

```
xts(DF$Close, as.Date(DF$Date, format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: I need the data in `ts` format because I need this object in forecasting.

Comment: @geektrader, shouldnt `format` be `format='%m/%d/%Y'`?

Comment: Ok fine, you suggest ... but why?  What makes xts better than ts?

Answer (score 7):

Here's an approach using `zoo` from zoo package and then coercing the result to be `ts`

```
> library(zoo)
> ZOO <- zoo(df$Close, order.by=as.Date(as.character(df$Date), format='%m/%d/%Y'))
> ZOO
2013-09-24 2013-09-25 2013-09-26 2013-09-27 2013-09-30 2013-10-01 2013-10-02 2013-10-03 2013-10-04 
    886.84     877.23     878.17     876.39     875.91     887.00     887.99     876.09     872.35 
2013-10-07 2013-10-08 2013-10-09 2013-10-10 2013-10-11 
    865.74     853.67     855.86     868.24     871.99 
> ts(ZOO)  # coercing to be `ts`
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 14 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 886.84 877.23 878.17 876.39 875.91 887.00 887.99 876.09 872.35 865.74 853.67 855.86 868.24
[14] 871.99
attr(,"index")
 [1] "2013-09-24" "2013-09-25" "2013-09-26" "2013-09-27" "2013-09-30" "2013-10-01" "2013-10-02"
 [8] "2013-10-03" "2013-10-04" "2013-10-07" "2013-10-08" "2013-10-09" "2013-10-10" "2013-10-11"
```

Comment: Thanks Jiber.. But when I am trying to `plot` above ts() object, I got some number like 0,50,100.... in x-axis but it should be `date`

Comment: @Ajay please read G. Grothendieck's explanation on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398705/create-a-ts-object-with-a-daily-timeseries).

Comment: The `zoo` approach is preferred when using the `forecast` package (since `zoo` is loaded when `forecast` is).