# creating time series for data sampled daily in R

Tags: r, time-series

I don't understand how time series objects are created in R.
I have data: `data = c(101,99,97,95,93,91,89,87,85,83,81)` (smaller dataset for the sake of brevity).
This data is taken once every day for 11 days starting from `2016-07-05` to `2016-07-15`. According to the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ts.html), the frequency for data sampled daily should be 7. But I do not understand the values for `start` and `end` parameters. For `start`, docs say: 
`the time of the first observation. Either a single number or a vector of two integers, which specify a natural time unit and a (1-based) number of samples into the time unit.` I do not understand what `1-based number of samples` means. I tried to google it but it didn't help.

If I just use `2016,7` as the start and end date, I just get:

```
Time Series:
Start = c(2016, 7) 
End = c(2016, 7) 
Frequency = 7 
[1] 101
```

If I use `2016,7,1` and `2016,7,11` as the start and end date, I still get the same output.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to switch to xts or zoo, since according to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398705/create-a-ts-object-with-a-daily-timeseries), ts() struggles with daily observations, since the number of days varies between years.

Comment: I am using time series for forecasting. I tried using `xts`, and it keeps the data in the format I expected (like the timestamp and the value for that timestamp). But the output, that I got from calling `forecast` using the xts object, is a `ts` object which does no longer contain those timestamps. I just see the values.

Comment: The only way of fixing this is by adding the dates manually back to the ts object as described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10347205/5795592
Don't know if it would be easier to just use a data.frame with a Date column.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood it, in the `ts()` function the unit is year. Therefore, here `frequency` should be set to 365 (days per year). Accordingly, `start` and `end` should represent days as well. However, (I believe that) to get the timing right, `start` and `end` should be the difference in days of the desired interval from the beginning of the year (in your specific case, 186 and 196 respectively). The appropriateness of these numbers can be checked with:

```
as.numeric(as.Date("2016-07-05") - as.Date("2016-01-01"))
[1] 186
as.numeric(as.Date("2016-07-15") - as.Date("2016-01-01"))
[1] 196
```

Embedding these information into your code the call to `ts()` should be:

```
data = c(101,99,97,95,93,91,89,87,85,83,81)
ts(data, start = c(2016, 186), end = c(2016, 196), frequency = 365)
# which yielded
Time Series:
Start = c(2016, 186) 
End = c(2016, 196) 
Frequency = 365 
 [1] 101  99  97  95  93  91  89  87  85  83  81
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

`Frequency` parameter in a `ts`object determines how many samples your series
has among units. Therefore, when you choose a frequency, it assumes a unit.
This unit is the one that will be used to set the `start`and `end` parameters.

For instance, if you set `frequency = 365`, you are assuming that the unit is year
and that there are 365 points sampled between units. Let us identify the first point
of you series at 2016-07-05 in this unit. Year is clearly 2016 and within that year
I take `as.Date("2016-07-05") - as.Date("2016-01-01") + 1`, that is 187. Note that
I'm assuming the first sampled day has index 1 instead of 0 as used in the solution
of @Helloworld. Therefore, `start = c(2016, 187)`.

```r
data <- c(101,99,97,95,93,91,89,87,85,83,81) 
start_dt <- "2016-07-05" 
end_dt <- "2016-07-15"

ts_365 <- ts(data, start = c(216, 187), frequency = 365)
ts_365
#> Time Series:
#> Start = c(216, 187) 
#> End = c(216, 197) 
#> Frequency = 365 
#>  [1] 101  99  97  95  93  91  89  87  85  83  81
```

On the other hand, if we want to use `frequency = 7`, we need to use week as unit
and use it to specify `start`. Indeed, we can obtain the week
(isoweek, but other criteria will work also) and the day of the week, assuming
Monday is the first day (again, you can change this criteria)

```r
strftime(start_dt, "isoweek: %V weekday: %u (%A)")
#> [1] "isoweek: 27 weekday: 2 (martes)"
```

With `frequency = 7`, we will define the time series as

```r
ts_7 <- ts(data, start = c(27, 2), frequency = 7)
ts_7
#> Time Series:
#> Start = c(27, 2) 
#> End = c(28, 5) 
#> Frequency = 7 
#>  [1] 101  99  97  95  93  91  89  87  85  83  81
```

If you plot any of the `ts` objects above, you will get a numeric axis based on the unit chosen.
My recommendation is that you set x axis to represent actual dates

```r
x_dates <- seq.Date(from = as.Date(start_dt), to = as.Date(end_dt), by = "day")
plot(x_dates, data)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The frequency you chose is relevant when you apply some functions to `ts` objects
because frequency can be taken as the period to look for seasonality
(`decompose()` function, for instance)